# How to copy paste all formats AND values without using select in vba

Tags: vba, select, copy, format, paste

How can I copy a range without using select. I need everything, not only the values.
Current bulky code:

```
Function Template(x As Integer)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:H5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, x).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Function
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Did the answers fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot guys! Much appreciated :-)

Comment: Great! You should accept one of the answers then! :0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Range.Copy` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx) to copy a range without the selection occurring, for instance ...

```
Range("A1").Copy Range("A2")
```

will copy everything including values and formats from `A1` to `A2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Template(x As Integer)
    Dim sourceRange As Excel.Range
    Dim destinationRange As Excel.Range

    Set sourceRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:H5")
    Call sourceRange.Copy


    Set destinationRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, x)
    Call destinationRange.PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)

End Function
```